# Couldn't resolve resource @android:color/... and invisible checkbox

Tags: android, android-resources, android-checkbox, invisible

I'm having this problem and I don't know when it started. I didn't have this problem before.

[image]

Because this error, the actual box from the `Checkbox` doesn't show up in `Android 5/6` but it does in `Android 4`. I mean this

[image]
[image]

I tested the app in different devices and

- 6.0.1 device -> No box.
- 5.1.1 device -> No box.
- 4.0.3 device -> Normal box.

I've tried to use `AppCompatCheckBox` directly instead `Checkbox`, but the error and the problem are still there.

**Gradle**

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aaa.bbb"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 15
    versionName "0.1"
    renderscriptTargetApi 23
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
```

---

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

What I missing? What I did?

Comment: can you write some code?

Comment: @skippy uh? wich code? The XML file is regular XML, a Checkbox inside a RelativeLayout, nothing special on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a style-related problem with Carbon library version 0.12.0. Downgrading to 0.11.0 fix it.